# Как реализовать "диалог" с пользователем после каждой перестановки в сортировке выбором?

Tags: c++, c

Массив сортируется методом выбора, в начале каждой итерации пользователя спрашивают показать ли ему следующую перестановку или показать сразу готовый отсортированный массив. Как можно реализовать такой "диалог"

```
void selection_sort(int* array, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < n - 1; ++i) {
        size_t min = i;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (array[j] < array[min]) {
            min = j;
            }
        }
    if (min != i)
        swap(array[i], array[min]);
    //меньший элемент на своем месте, показываем результат
    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        cout << array[k] <<' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы заранее отсортируйте массив, в функцию `selection_sort` отдавайте два массива - отсортированный и исходный. Ну и там где вы в цикле выводите на очередной итерации массив, сначала спрашивайте у пользователя, что он хочет. Если весь отсортированный массив, то показываете отсортированный, если перестановку - то перестановку.

Comment: Прочитал ваш предыдущий вопрос. Один из вариантов. Делаете вывод в консоль (`std::cout`) с вопросом что показывать и просьбой ввести (`std::cin`) число, далее читаете число, если оно 1 - выводите перестановку, если 2 - выводите отсортированный массив. Типа : `Выберите тип выводимой информации: 1) вывод очередной перестановки 2) вывод отсортированного массива` Далее пользователь вводит число (1 или 2), а вы с помощью `if` обрабатываете то что ввёл пользователь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите ввести диалог в ходе сортировки

```
 void selection_sort(int* array, size_t n)
    {
        std::string s = "yes";
        for (size_t i = 0;  i < n - 1; ++i) {
            size_t min = i;
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
                if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }

        if (min != i)
            swap(array[i], array[min]);
        //меньший элемент на своем месте, показываем результат
        if (s == "yes" ) {
            cout << "вы хотите видить результат каждой итерации введите \"yes\""
                  << ",  в обратном случаи  введите \"no\"" << endl;
            cin >> s;
            if (s == "no" && i != n - 2) continue;                
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n; ++k) 
                cout << array[k] <<' ';                    
            cout << endl;                
        }
    }
    if (s == "no")
        for (size_t k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            cout << array[k] <<' ';
}
```

Comment: вы там сами выберите диалог на киррилице или нет